# Google Maps web integration not displayed in an AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps

I was trying to integrate **Google Maps** in my **AngularJS** Application. First, i tried to use **[NGMap](http://angular-js.in/ng-map/)** and the Map is not shown, so i tried the official **Google Maps API** for javascript but it still invisible.

Here is my piece of HTML

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Mark your location</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <div id="map"></div>
                <!--div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
                </div-->
                <!--div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
                    <ng-map center="41,-87" zoom="3"></ng-map>
                </div-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save coordinates</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 35.675914, lng: 10.091924},
            zoom: 8
        });
    }
</script>
```

**

> Notice That i tried both of the 2 methods in an empty web page and
>   it's working pretty well but in my AngularJS Application it still
>   invisible.

**

Comment: needs to be implemented in a directive and since it;s a modal will have to trigger map resize after modal opens

Comment: Is there any size specifications for Google Maps?

Comment: yes you have to set container size in css. But aspect ratio isn't critical

Comment: The container you mean: <div id="map"></div> ?